# MySql create database using Makefile

Tags: mysql, docker, makefile

```
include .env

help:
    @echo ""
    @echo "usage: make COMMAND"
    @echo ""
    @echo "Commands:"
    @echo "  mysql-create-db     Create mysql database"

mysql-create-db:
    @docker-compose exec -T mysqldb mysql -u"$(MYSQL_USER)" -p"$(MYSQL_PASSWORD)" -e \'create database abcd\'
```

it also throws error for simple "show databases" query also.

I am not sure why it is not working

Comment: You say "it throws error", but leave out the details when asking a question for help. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 4):

First rule of asking questions on SO: *always* include the command you typed and the output you got, cut and pasted into your question.  If the output is too long and messy to include, then at the very least always include the actual error or incorrect output you got, and a few lines before and after it for context.

First rule of writing makefiles: *never* add in `@` until your makefile works completely.  You're shooting yourself in the foot by hiding critical details.  Alternatively, read http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/ for another way of handling this.

Second rule of writing makefiles: *always* make sure your commands work when you type the at the shell command line before you try to add it to a makefile recipe.

I don't know much about docker but my suspicion is that this is a shell quoting problem not a make problem... I suspect this command wouldn't work if you cut-and-pasted to a shell prompt.  That's because I think your quoting is wrong.

Try this instead (note the different quoting of the mysql command):

```
mysql-create-db:
        @docker-compose exec -T mysqldb mysql -u"$(MYSQL_USER)" -p"$(MYSQL_PASSWORD)" -e "'create database abcd'"
```

This ensures that the final command is a single word, that includes quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but I get this error:

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''create database abcd'' at line 1
make: *** [mysql-create-db] Error 1

Comment: @docker-compose exec -T mysqldb mysql -u"$(MYSQL_USER)" -p"$(MYSQL_PASSWORD)" -e 'create database abcd'

This seems to work

Comment: OK.  As I said I'm not that familiar with docker.  I wasn't sure why you wanted to escape the quotes so I figured they were needed but I guess not.

Comment: looks like too many quotes near create database abcd, after removing single quotes I got it working